# Serialize a vector of floats

Tags: c++, boost, xcode4, stdvector

The problem is that I want to save a 2D vector of float in a file. since I am not familiar with C++ which is becoming troublesome, possible ways to solve are:

1. Serializing them in a string and write to a file.
2. Serializing them to binary data and write to a file.

Which one of the two methods could be more efficient in terms of speed?

I am doing something like:

```
std::string serialized;

    for (int s = 0; s < (int) mfcc_features_a.size(); s++)
     {

     for (int t = 0; t < (int) mfcc_features_a[s].size(); t++){
       serialized = serialized + "|" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(mfcc_features_a[s][t]);
     }
     }

    std::cout << "serialized string is: " << serialized << std::endl;
```

Comment: "which could be more efficient in terms of speed?" - benchmark...

Comment: less time or less cpu cycles, like some parsers are fast some are slow

Comment: @MitchWheat It's quite reasonable to expect direct binary reads/writes perform faster than the same plus conversions.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze: I said "benchmark", not which way was faster...

Comment: right, can you correct my code with binary format replica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing binary data is liable to be somewhat faster, since the data will almost certainly be smaller. The difference may or may not be significant to the overall performance of your program: you'd have to measure in order to find out.

In C++03 there is a major inefficiency in your code. `specialized = specialized + "|" + ...` creates gradually longer and longer copies of the full data, three copies per float value. Either use `+=`, or write the data directly to a stream. In C++11 you could solve it by writing `specialized = std::move(specialized) + "|" + ...`

Comment: any better way to build serialized string other than looping and concatenating this way, I dont have c++ knowledge much

Answer (score 1):

While binary is certain to be faster to execute, it can be troublesome to code and debug, as floating point formats are poorly understood by most programmers.  In this respect, the overall time programming plus execution could be slower.

Also, if portability of the data to any other machine is desired, almost certainly it is worthwhile to convert to a universally readable format.

Answer (score 0):

Although not very C++'ish, I like to use the `sprintf` routine to format the floating point values up to a fixed width string (24 characters).

```
char *pData = new char[vec.size() * 24 + 1];
char *p = pData;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i, p += 24)
    sprintf(p, "%+.14E\r\n", vec(i));


// ... write pData to file ...

delete[] pData;
```

Good luck!